# Allow non admin users to upload a photo a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to write a facebook app using Facebook C# sdk 5.1.1. The app should let the users to upload a picture to a Facebook page. I was able to write the app where only the admins of the page are able to upload the picture but not users. Even if the user has liked that page I am not able to do it.

I know its possible because on iPhone or from web site you can visit a page and write something on wall or share a photo. But I am not able to figure out how to do it using Facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

the user of the application needs to grant the publish_stream permissions.

You can then make a call to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<page_id>/feed?message=<yourmessage>&picture=<picture_url>&access_token=<access_token>&method=POST.
```

You can try this first by using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it. Using page_ID/feed if I try to post a photo photo is not getting uploaded. If I use Page_ID/Photos then it is publishing photo to the user account. Not to the page.

Comment: Are you trying to post as a user (non-admin of the page) or as the admin of the page or as the page itself? Can you post the exact request that is not working please? Also, which permissions have you granted to the app?